# How can I send all URL´s with index.php? to 404 error page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need a rewrite rule that makes all URL´s with /index.php?/... to 404 error page.

I tried this but that didn't work :

```
RewriteRule ^directory/ - [L,R=404]
```

Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: before you ask a question you should try and search first, and maybe this page will help you:https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on the top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php?\/(.*)$ /404-error-page.php [R=301,L]
```